# Join and Count Tables in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

thanks to the help i have gotten on Stackoverflow while learning php i am able to Join tables and use Count.

I am unable to do both in one query.

I am wanting to count records in a joined table.
This is what i have tryed and i seem to get errors:

```
$options = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'toutcome.AffCommission',
    ),
    'joins' => array(

        array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'tapplicant.AppID = toutcome.AppID',
            ),
            'table' => 'toutcome',
            'alias' => 'Toutcome',
            'type' => 'join',
        ),
    ),
    'limit' => 'Toutcome',
    'offset' => 'Toutcome',
    'contain' => array(
        'Toutcome',
    ),
);

$data = $this->Tapplicant->find('count', $options);
$this->set('count', $data );
```

Comment: Hi @Miam84 , do you think you could assist on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$options = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'toutcome.AffCommission',
    ),
    'joins' => array(

        array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'tapplicant.AppID = toutcome.AppID',
            ),
            'table' => 'toutcome',
            'alias' => 'Toutcome',
            'type' => 'join',
        ),
    ),
    'limit' => n, // its should be integer
    'offset' => n, // its should be integer
    'contain' => array(
        'Toutcome',
    ),
);
```